# how to update two tables with db: transaction laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

this is my Video model code

```
    class Video extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'lokit_video';
    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'title',
        'cover_img',
        'trailer',
        'url',
        'order_',
        'active',
        'description',
        'lokit_category_id',
        'duration'
    ];
    public function lokit_category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function video_series() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(VideoSeries::class, 'lokit_video_id');
    } 
 }
```

this is my VideoSeries Model code

```
    class VideoSeries extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'lokit_video_series';
    protected $fillable = [
        'lokit_video_id',
        'lokit_series_id',
        'series',
        
    ];

    public function lokit_video(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Video::class, 'lokit_video_id');
    }

    public function serie(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Series::class, 'lokit_series_id');
    }
}
```

in my code controller

```
        public function update(Request $request,$id) {
        $data = $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'title'                  => 'required',
            'order_'  => 'required',
            'active'               => 'required',
            'url'               => 'required',
            'category'           => 'required'
        ]);
        $errors=$validator->errors();
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('admin/video/video/'.$id.'/edit')
                ->withErrors($errors)
                ->withInput();
        }
        $data['lokit_category_id'] = $data['category'];
        unset($data['category']);
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            if($request->hasFile('cover_img')) {
                $uniquename='cvr_'.md5($id);
                $filename=$uniquename.'.'.$request->file('cover_img')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path=public_path('storage/media');
                $request->cover_img->move($path, $filename);
                $data['cover_img']=$filename;
                
                $this->_resizeimg($path,$filename,$uniquename);  
            }
            $isi = Video::find($id);
            if($isi->url != $data['url']) {
                $name = str_replace("_", '',$data['url']);
                $manager = new MediaManager('/uploads');
                $manager->newFolder($name);
                $data['duration'] = $this->getDuration($data['url']);
            }
            
            $isi->update($data);
            if (isset($request->series) && $request->series) {
                $video_series = new VideoSeries();
                $video_series->lokit_video_id =$id;
                $video_series->lokit_series_id = (int)$request->series;
                $video_series->series = (int)$request->episode;
                $isi->video_series()->update($video_series);
            }
            DB::commit();
            return Redirect::to('admin/video/video');
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            DB::rollback();
            throw $ex;
        }
   

     }
```

When I tried the code above, I even experienced errors such as Argument 1 that was passed to Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ Builder :: update () must be of the array type, the object given, how can I fix this error and why did I get the error?

Comment: Please share the models and schema in the post and explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: I have shared my model code

Answer (score 0):

You need [attach](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) as there is such method like `update()` for updating the primary and foreign keys of relating tables

So this is wrong `$isi->video_series()->update($video_series);`

Instead use

```
$isi->video_series()->attach($video_series);
```

Comment: I tried your code instead, there was an error like Call to undefined method Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ Relations \ HasMany :: attach ()

Comment: It seems you haven't configured (hasMany) relation between `Video` and `VideoSeries` model

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
$isi->video_series()->update($video_series);
```

You don't need to make an update statement as above as you've already added the video's id in the lokit_video_id while creating video_series entry. (`$video_series->lokit_video_id =$id;`)

But you need to save that model instance. So do this

```
$video_series->save();
```

Comment: I'd like to give one more suggestion. As far as I can tell the video_series is a pivot table, so why not have a many to many relation between video and series. This way you won't have to create VideoSeries model, and Video and Series model will be linked directly. Let me know what you think about this.